# Get files From SFTP to S3 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

What is the better option of get data from a directory in SFTP and copy in bucket of S3 of AWS? **In SFTP i only have permission of read** so Rsync isn't option.

My idea is create a job in GLUE with Python that download this data y copy in bucket of S3. They are different files, one weighs about 600 MB, others are 4 GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about an sFTP server that is not on AWS, you have a few different options that may be easier than what you have proposed (although your solution could work):

1. Download the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) onto the sFTP server and copy the files via the `AWS s3 cp` command.
2. Write a script using the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) that takes the files and copies them. You may need to use the multi-part upload with the size of your files.
3. Your can create an [AWS managed sFTP server](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-transfer-family/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) that links directly to your s3 bucket as the backend storage for that server, then use `sftp` commands to copy the files over.

Be mindful that you will need the appropriate permissions in your AWS account to complete any of these 3 (or 4) solutions.

Comment: The first option is not available. On the SFTP server I only have reader permission. I cannot install another service.

The second option that I am testing with paramiko but with multi-part loading is missing MB.

The third option I have not tried but I have doubts. Can I bring from files from another Sftp to the AWS Transfer Family? considering that the capture instructions I must say them in AWS.